# Why return in forEach of Map doesn't interrupt

Tags: typescript

In order to iterate a map in Typescript.

The `forEach` won't be interrupted. Strangely the key and value have to be inverted.

The `for` works correctly.

```
    const map = new Map<number, number>()
    const uniq = new Set<number>();

    // won't return anything if condition is true
    map.forEach( (v,k) => { // moreover , k and v are inverted 
        if(uniq.has(v)) return false
        uniq.add(v)
    });

    // will work
    for (const [_, v] of map.entries()) {
        if(uniq.has(v)) return false
        uniq.add(v)
    }
```

Why `forEach` doesn't break or return ?

Comment: Edit : found it `There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example

Comment: "*Why forEach doesn't break or return ?*" because that's how `.forEach()` works, which is behaviour not at all related to maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.forEach` method accept a function as argument that will be called on *each* element of the iterable.

The `return` keyword ends the current execution of it's function, this is why you can't exit from a `forEach` with a simple `return`, it will exit only the current function call with the element, it won't exit the `forEach`.